# When a youth's voice becomes "manly"

Tags: word-request, idioms, expressions, phrases

I wonder how would you talk about a voice breaking in young males - around the age of puberty?
This is when they lose their high-pitched voices and start to produce deeper sounds.
What shall I say:

> 1- His voice has gotten manly. 
>   2- He has gotten a manly voice.

I am quite confidents there should be an idiom/expression for that, while once I heard something like that; though I cannot recall.

Comment: There is a colloquial phrase in this previous English Language & Usage [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195433/balls-have-dropped-what-does-it-mean). Don't use it in polite society.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is in your question:

> His voice has broken.

[Dictionary definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-s-voice-breaks)